# Futures Market Books

Tags: finance, reference-request, financial-markets, commodities, agriculture

Are there any recommendation for futures market or commodity trading books? I am not interested in trading myself, but would like to have a better understanding of it for my research.

Comment: http://www.amazon.co.uk/Options-Futures-Other-Derivatives-John/dp/0131499084 might help.

Comment: Thanks @pidosaurus, I will look into it. Have you personally read it? Did you find it helpful?

Comment: As @pidosaurus says, John Hull is the standard introduction to options and futures book.

Comment: @pidosaurus You might consider converting your comment to an answer. If you add a sentence about why you think the book would be good, I think it would be a fine answer.

Comment: @pidosaurus Have you considered the option of turning your comment into an answer?

Comment: Less academic and more fun: 'the world for sale'. Haven't read it, but it should bring a practical view on commodity trading.

Answer (score 2):

##### See [What are the quantitative finance books that we should all have in our shelves?](https://quant.stackexchange.com/q/38862)

It mooted *Options, Futures and Other Derivatives* by John Hull.

##### [Futures trading](https://old.reddit.com/r/FuturesTrading/comments/gte11q/im_about_to_dive_into_futures_any_recommended/fsb2uvq)

Abell, Howard - Spread Trading [2002]

Aikin, Stephen - STIR Futures [2nd Ed., 2012]

Bennett, David - Day Trading Grain Futures [2009]

Bowen, Guy - Guide to Futures and Spread Trading [2009]

Chou, Robin; Wang, Yun-Yi - Strategic Order Splitting, Order Choice, and Aggressiveness [2009]

Clenow, Andreas - Following the Trend [2013]

Collins, Art - Beating the Financial Futures Market [2006]

Dobson, Edward; Reimer, Roger - Understanding Spreads [2007]

Duarte, Joe - Trading Futures for Dummies [2008]

Garner, Carley - Currency Trading in the Forex and Futures Markets [2012]

George Angell, Barry Haigh - West of Wall Street [1987]

Goslin, Chick - Intelligent Futures Trading [1998]

Goss, Barry - Debt, Risk and Liquidity in Futures Markets [2008]

Goss, Barry; Yamey, Basil - The Economics of Futures Trading [1976]

Greyserman, Alex; Kaminski, Kathryn - Trend following with Managed Futures [2014]

Gutmann, Michael - The Very Latest E-Mini Trading [2009]

Henrard, Marc - Interest Rate Modelling in the Multi-Curve Framework [2014]

Hull, John C. - Fundamentals of Futures and Options Markets [10th Ed., 2018]

Kaeppel, Jay - The Four Biggest Mistakes In Futures Trading [2000]

Kroll, Stanley - Kroll on Futures Trading Strategy [1987]

Labuszewski, John et al. - The CME Group Risk Management Handbook [2010]

Lind-Waldock - The Complete Guide to Futures Trading [2005]

Lofton, Todd - Getting started in Futures [5th Ed., 2005]

Powers, Mark - Starting out in Futures Trading [6th Ed., 2001]

Refco Private Client Group - The Complete Guide to Futures Trading [2005]

Rhoads, Russell - Trading VIX Derivatives [2011]

Schwager, Jack; Etzkorn, Mark - A Complete Guide to the Futures Market [2nd Ed., 2017]

Smith, Courtney - Futures Spread Trading [2000]

Spence, Donald - Introduction to Futures and Options [1997]

Thomsett, Michael - Winning with Futures [2009]

Williams, Larry - Trade Stocks and Commodities with the Insiders [2005]

#### [Commodities](https://old.reddit.com/r/Commodities/comments/gu44i9/book_recommendations_for_new_commodity_trader/fsg8oid/)

- *Trading Option Greeks* by Dan Passarelli

Why a book on options when you asked about trading commodities? Not only can you trade futures contracts themselves, but you can trade options on futures. I rarely trade naked futures and will usually long an option the same time I open a futures position as a hedge. Besides using options as a hedge, you might want to trade FOs as a way to make money. This book describes the ins and outs of options: the Greeks, taking long and short positions, spread strategies, volatility, etc. It goes into great detail and I highly recommend it. If you're already familiar with how options work you can skip it.

- *A Trader's First Book on Commodities* by Carley Garner

This book is definitely for those new to commodities. It even goes over some basic trading concepts. You'll learn about the history of the futures market, how a futures contract works, how it's traded, different kinds of brokers and trading platforms and what they allow, market data fees, order types, the various product groups and their futures, and finally some general trading advice.

- *Higher Probability Commodity Trading* by Carley Garner

Also by the same author, this goes into more detail about researching and trading. It discusses technical and fundamental analysis, seasonality, COT, trading strategies, spreads, trading options (including going short), hedging with options, and risk management.

See also  [*Futures 101* by Richard Wauldron](https://old.reddit.com/r/Commodities/comments/o298cc/best_books_on_commodities_for_someone_looking_to/h257wp1),

- https://old.reddit.com/r/Commodities/comments/aaq7ak/recommended_books/ehax86z,
- https://old.reddit.com/r/Commodities/comments/122rsxi/anyone_have_any_good_book_recommendations_for/jdsga34.